# What does "x-y" denote in boolean logic?

Tags: notation, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I came across this equation in set theory :
**`x-y = y'-x'`**
*where x and y are sets*
If it was a "+" or "." , I could easily correlate it with OR and AND function.
But what does this "**-**" indicate in boolean logic?
 It indicates Set difference in set theory. 
Is it complement ? But complement is denoted by " **'** " here.

Comment: In which context?

Comment: x+y denotes element is either in x or in y from set theory perspective. From boolean perspective, its like 0+1 = 1; I want to know the boolean perspective of "x-y"

Comment: There is no operation x-y in Boolean algebra, eventually $x+y'$.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm curious to know. What will "x-y" translate to in boolean logic. I'm sure that this equation has 2 views : set and the boolean view. Set view gets complicated as set size increases, that is why, I want to know the boolean view.

Comment: I think $x-y$ denotes the addition of $x$ and the complement of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This says that $x$ and $y$ are sets. Denoting the complement of $z$ by $z'$, we have that
$$x-y=x\cap y'$$
Intuitively, you are taking only the elements of $x$ that are not elements of $y$. This does not require $y$ to be a subset of $x$.

As you can work out,
$$y'-x'=y'\cap (x')'=y'\cap x$$
so you can see the equivalence.

For the connection with Boolean logic, this is $x.y'$, or in the notation I am used to $x\wedge \neg y$.

Comment: In Boolean logic?

Comment: @Wuestenfux What is your objection? By the way, though it would seem logical, $x-y\neq x+y'$. It's $x.y'$ as in my answer. You're supposed to be doing an and, not an or.

Comment: Oh, yes that works perfectly well. LHS = x-y = x.y'; RHS = y'-x' = y'.(x')' = y'.x. So both sides equal now. And it is because x-y = x ∩ y' = x.y'. Thank you !

Comment: @SpawN You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

*Conclusion :* 
Set view : **x - y**  = Elements in x but not in y 
Focusing on terms "x", "BUT" which translates to "AND", "NOT" in y
Thus, Boolean view became x.y'
*Other Set to Boolean views:*
x ∩ y = Elements common to both = x.y
x ∪ y = Elements in both combined = x+y
x' = Elements not in x = x'
x Δ y = Elements in x or y but not in both =  x ⊕ y = x.y' + x'.y

*Uses of these boolean views over set views* : 
You don't need to go through the trouble of finding counter examples to prove any equation wrong. Just show it with boolean logic and put values for x,y as 0 or 1 and see it it satisfies.